# Moving local std::array to passed std::array& argument

Tags: c++, stdarray

I'm confused in terms of moving std::array operation to a reference passed std::array container.

Where I've read comments that
Is this considered undefined behavior, or it's the correct results?

Or do it really copy the elements?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void printElements(string description, array<uint8_t,16>& arr)
{
    cout << description << ":\t";
    for(auto i:arr)
    {
        cout << (int)i << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

void assignToArr(array<uint8_t,16>& in_out_arr)
{
    array<uint8_t,16> arr2;
    arr2.fill(4);
    move(arr2.begin(),arr2.end(),in_out_arr.begin());
    printElements("before arr2 destruction", in_out_arr);
    printElements("arr2 before fill(5)", arr2);
    arr2.fill(5);
    printElements("arr2 after fill(5)", arr2);
}

int main()
{
    array<uint8_t,16> arr1;
    assignToArr(arr1);
    
    printElements("after arr2 destruction", arr1);
    

    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
before arr2 destruction:        4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4                                                                                      
arr2:   4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4                                                                                                              
arr2:   5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5                                                                                                              
after arr2 destruction: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 2):

When you move a trivial type in C++, it is copied.

The move operation in C++ is telling the type that "we do not rely on the source data being what it was afterwards, feel free to do something more efficient".  For trivial types (like `int`), there is no benefit to zeroing or otherwise changing the source.

So it doesn't.

For more complex types, like `std::vector<int>`, a move-from will usually result in an empty `std::vector<int>` (not always!  There is no guarantee; just that the old vector will be valid to assign over or destroy).

std array stores its data internally, so there is no efficient move improvement if the types in turn are trivial (it itself is trivial if the data in it is).

Trivial here refers to a term used in the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

`std::array` stores elements directly inside the array object. That's why its size must be a compile-time constant. When you try to move a `std::array`, the array itself isn't moved as that would be impossible, but the elements inside are moved. What happens to the objects when moved depends on the types. In general, cheap to copy types (`int`, `double`, etc) are copied with no effect on the copied-from objects. More complicate objects (`std::string`, and other containers) are moved from and the moved-from object is left in an "unspecified" state. Meaning it's not undefined behavior, but rather unspecified behavior. Here's an illustration:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class Stateful final {
 private:
  bool m_specifiedState = true;
  int m_value = 0;

 public:
  bool hasSpecified() const noexcept { return m_specifiedState; }
  int value() const noexcept { return m_value; }
  Stateful(int val) noexcept : m_value(val) {}

  Stateful(Stateful const& other) noexcept = default;
  Stateful& operator=(Stateful const& other) noexcept = default;

  Stateful(Stateful&& other) noexcept
      : m_specifiedState(other.m_specifiedState), m_value(other.m_value) {
    other.m_specifiedState = false;
  }

  Stateful& operator=(Stateful&& other) noexcept {
    if (this != &other) {
      m_specifiedState = other.m_specifiedState;
      m_value = other.m_value;
      other.m_specifiedState = false;
    }
    return *this;
  }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Stateful const& s) {
  if (s.hasSpecified())
    os << s.value();
  else
    os << '?';
  return os;
}

template <auto N>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::array<Stateful, N> const& arr) {
  os << "[ ";
  for (auto const& elm : arr) os << elm << ' ';
  os << "]";
  return os;
}

int main() {
  std::array<Stateful, 3> arr1{1, 2, 3};

  std::cout << "Arr1             :" << arr1 << '\n';

  std::array<Stateful, 3> arr2 = std::move(arr1);
  std::cout << "Arr1 (moved from):" << arr1 << '\n';
  std::cout << "Arr2 (moved to)  :" << arr2 << '\n';
}
```

<kbd>[See Online](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nWY88js5c)</kbd>

The output is:

```
Arr1             :[ 1 2 3 ]
Arr1 (moved from):[ ? ? ? ]
Arr2 (moved to)  :[ 1 2 3 ]
```

As you can see the moved-from array is still there and still has 3 elements, but the elements themselves are moved.

Comment: Stack is the wrong term here.  `auto* foo = new std::array<int,3>{1,2,3};` doesn't store elements on the stack, for example, but is a std array.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I reworded it. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own confusion-ness, the `std::array` doesn't store references, it stored objects directly in the stack. So they're not movable, but are actually copied.

Comment: Whether or not elements are copied or moved is down to the elements, not the `std::array`. Your `std::array` contains type `uint8_t` which creates a copy when you try to move it. That will not be true for all types you may store in a `std::array`.

Comment: Also `std::array` dosn' t store its objects on the stack unless you create the array itself on the stack. The point is the `std::array` stores its elements inside itself so if you create it on the stack, its elements will also be on the stack and if you create on the heap its elements will also be on the heap. That has nothing to do with whether or not an object is "moveable".